# Buttons stop working in landscape mode

Tags: tablet, buttons

I wanna buy a second hand tablet (Pierre Cardin 7558) whose home and return buttons stop working when tilting to widescreen. The quality is good in comparison with the price, but there is this problem.

Is there any workaround to it? Like a Rom update or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons are disabled so that users can grip the sides without causing and action. It would be difficult holding the device if the user is causing the device to go to the home screen.

Comment: Thanks.But why should they be shown if they're not there to be used?

Comment: You said that they are disabled on widescreen so, they work on regular screen.

Comment: It is also easier to simply disable a button than to also remove. Lazy programmer maybe?

Comment: So it means that's the same thing in most of tabs, am I right?

Comment: I am starting to think that I am not understanding your question. Can you clarify what you are wanting to know?

Comment: Actually it's a second hand device and the one of the reasons the seller i giving it away is the buttons not working in widescreen.